# Swift 4 - Pass Data To TableView Embedded In Collection View Cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm creating a weather app in swift. There is a main view controller and within the controller, there is a collection view with two cells. In each cell there is a tableview.

In the view controller, there is a network call and an array is filled with data. The goal is to pass this data into each tableview cell to display it

I have created a diagram to display how the collection view and tableviews are set out.

[image: Diagram]

If there is a way to do this then any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The way to populate `UITableViewCell` is to override the `cellForRowAt:` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

However, the data must first be passed to the `UICollectionViewCell`. Similarly, this is also achieved by overriding the `cellForItemAt:` method.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
      cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
```

So you could **sub-class** `UICollectionViewCell` and declare a custom member variable to store the data. Also, make the sub-class conform to the `UITableViewDataSource`'s protocol, so that you have to override the `UITableViewDataSource`'s `cellForRowAt:` method. From there, you could also refer to **another sub-class** of `UITableViewCell`, which will also possess a custom member variable that would store the data. Finally, customize the `UITableViewCell` subclass on how to display the data.